# What is this badge that appears in certain GitHub issue comments?

Tags: github, github-issues

In a node.js repo, the text "Node.js Foundation member" appears in the tile bar for all of a particular user's comments:

[image: GitHub issue comment with "Node.js Foundation member" badge in title]

However, note that the extra text is missing from a comment by the same user in a different repo:

[image: GitHub issue comment by same user in different repo, no badge appears in title]

What is the name for this feature?  Is there a setting I can configure to apply it to users/repos within my organization?

Examples:

- [badge example 1](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/25909#issuecomment-167865964)
- [no badge example 1](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6515#issuecomment-238738288)
- [badge example 2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8110#issuecomment-239815215)
- [no badge example 2](https://github.com/nucleus-js/rustyduk/issues/14#issuecomment-239677437)

Answer (score 2):

GitHub has a feature called "Organizations". You can make one: Just go to Profile-Dropdown > Settings > Organizations (about four from the bottom on the left).

Then on the top right will be a [New organization] button.

You just have to give it a name and you're good to go. You could try "Node.js Floundation"?

I've used these groups to have multiple clones of a repository under the same user name but they often also bestow commit privileges or similar.

So in the first comment SRL had been working under his Node.js org and later on his was just logged in without an org, probably working on a personal repository.